# Special monomorphism to encode the inclusion of topological submonoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, topological-groups, semigroups-and-monoids

Consider the category $\mathrm{TopMon}$ of topological monoids and continuous monoid homomorphisms.
Consider the inclusion $i:\Bbb{R}_{\ge 0}\hookrightarrow \Bbb{R}$, where the spaces are taken with their usual topology and addition as the monoid operation. This is map is a monomorphism. Compare it now with the (still injective) map $j:\Bbb{R}_{\ge 0, D}\hookrightarrow \Bbb{R}$, where $\Bbb{R}_{\ge 0, D}$ is now the monoid $(\Bbb{R}_{\ge 0},+,0)$ equipped with the *discrete* topology.

I'm looking for a formal (category-theoretical) way to express that $i$ is "nicer" than $j$, since for example $i$ is the inclusion of a subspace, while $j$ is not. However, 
$i$ is not strong mono, nor extremal mono (since it is *epi* as well), nor regular mono, et cetera. Is there a class which is less restrictive than strong or extremal mono to which $i$ belongs, but not $j$?

Of course, one possible way would be to take the obvious forgetful functor $U:\mathrm{TopMon}\to\mathrm{Top}$ and say that $Ui$ is extremal mono, while $Uj$ is not. However, I was wondering if there is a way to distinguish the two which is internal to $\mathrm{TopMon}$.

Comment: I think this is related to studying the map of subobjects $j\to i$: this map is a bimorphism, but not an isomorphism. Perhaps the exsitence of such a bimorphism could be interesting ?